# document.getElementById() only operated on one element

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple `const divFrame = document.getElementById("ethto-adfr")` and I use `document.createElement("iframe")` and `divFrame.appendChild(createFrame)` to create an iframe at the `<div`s with the `id` of `ethto-adfr`. It works great... but only on the first `<div>` in the page. Is this just the way that `document.getElementById` works? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, hence why *many* things may break if you have duplicates. The errors aren't even going to be grand but a lot of tools may very well assume there is a single ID and only use the first element they find. Some *might* return multiple items but only because they've been made very generic, not because multiple IDs are expected.

Comment: id = one. Just like your stackoverflow username :)

Comment: @ButWhyTho1375 Like yiffyiffyiff said Id is for a unique element, you can use a class to reference the other divs or even a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the fact that there can only be one unique id per html page, then that's how it's supposed to work. If you want to select multiple elements, you want to use class.

```html
<div class="some_class_name"></div>
<div class="some_class_name"></div>
<div class="some_class_name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @vlaz , IDs should be unique.

That being said, `document.querySelectorAll('#ethto-adfr')` might do the trick

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. Yes, it can work but the page is still invalid. There are a surprising amount of things that can fail if you work with an element with a duplicate ID and it's predominantly small and hard to find and diagnose bugs.

Comment: It can be fine, if it's in a framework such as VueJS, React, ect. But yeah, I agree 100% it's not good practice

Comment: A problem I've seen is that a library might pick up the element, see it has an ID, and then try to update it by its ID or something similar. And that might be something small like a validation library, so it might misplace where the validation message shows up. Or maybe a library that presents fancy tooltips does something similar. Anything using jQuery is susceptible since `$("#id")` only returns one item - Sizzle checks the selector and if it finds it's only an ID it goes for the more optimised lookup by ID.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are meant to be unique for an HTML page, you can instead use class for using in multiple places.

```
 <div class="ethto-adrf"> ... </div>
 <div class="ethto-adrf"> ... </div>


 document.getElementsByClassName("ethto-adfr")
```